# How do we define a metric on Dyadic set in $\Bbb R$?

Tags: metric-spaces

I was trying to define a metric on Dyadic Set in $\Bbb R$ and find open sets on it. But I was unable to define any metric. Any clue in this direction will be very helpful!

Comment: Please try to write your thoughts or ideas.

Comment: What do you mean by "Dyadic Set"? [if it's a subset of the reals, why can't you just use the metric it inherits from the reals?]

Comment: By Dyadic set, I mean the set of Dyadic Rationals in R. I was stuck in the initial stage itself. I will try the metric inherited from R. Thanks!